# load and plot dataframes in loop using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[path structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TONrs.png)

hi everyone,
please  I am a beginner in Python, i would like to use "for" loop to load and plot multiple dataframes from different folders on the same graph (as shown in the picture ) , i started to write a script, but i got stuck , please if you can help me with this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

f= ("40","50","60")
for i in f:
  for j in range(6):                   
      pd.read_csv(os.path.join("/Simulation_Results/10km/","res_"f"{i}",f"sim_{str(j).zfill(3)}","velocity.csv"),sep='\s+',header=None)
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the data?  You're certainly loading the CSV files now, but you're not storing them anywhere.

Comment: Driss Welcome to SO, what plots are you looking at plotting?

Comment: as shown on the figure, i would like to plot  the data from  "sim_000" together  , and  the  "sim_001".. separately . 
how can plot them if you have an idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the frames.  I don't know how you expect to use them, but here's one way:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

f= ("40","50","60")
storage = {}
for i in f:
  for j in range(6):
     storage[(i,j)] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("/Simulation_Results/10km/","res_"f"{i}",f"sim_{str(j).zfill(3)}","velocity.csv"),sep='\\s+',header=None)
```

That creates a dictionary, where `storage[("40",3)]`, for example, will contain one the the dataframes.

Comment: thanks a lot @Tim, the only thing missing now , is that I want to plot  the "storage[("40",j)] " and storage[("50",j)] and storage[("60",j)]  TOGETHER on the same plot  using a loop ,

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different problem.  You don't have any plotting yet.  Try to make this work, then ask another question.